# Extra file creation on save is an error

Tags: php, xml, drupal, dom, drupal-6

Hi StackOverflow friends.

Running Drupal 6.22 php 5.3

I have been looking around now for a while, but haven't managd to find a solution to my problem.

I am hoping someone may be able to help me out with this.

I need to write an xml file from my data held in an array.
I have written this code and it works fine without problems.

I have invoked this to run on every cron run to ensure my data is upto date,
however I am no getting a second folder my_file.xml.imported and this is causing me problems.

I am using xml2node and hotfolders to import this data into my specified content type.

What bothers me most is that I had this working last week, all I have done since is put an extra "filter" on my data being written to the xml file.

Does anyone know what this .imported file type is and how I can stop it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured this out, hopefully if someone else comes across this problem, this may help them.

The .imported file is created by the xml2node module after the xml file has been processed and put into the drupal queue.

When xml2node then searches again for xml files, it deletes all the .imported files so that your server does not get overloaded with useless once off files.